# Line Space in chunk itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How do i reduce line space in **itextsharp**.
I am using ***chunk*** to add a paragraph in **itextsharp**
  Though my code working fine ,but i want to reduce the gap between two lines.

> Here is My code

```
     BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false);               
     iTextSharp.text.Font fontH5 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 8);

          Chunk c3 = new Chunk("xyz", fontH5 );
          Chunk c4 = new Chunk("xyz11", fontH5 );                        


          Phrase p2 = new Phrase();
          p2.Add(c3);                      

          Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
          p.Add(p2);
          pdfDoc.Add(p);
          pdfDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a **Leading**..

```
     BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false);               
     iTextSharp.text.Font fontH5 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 8);

          Chunk c3 = new Chunk("xyz", fontH5 );
          Chunk c4 = new Chunk("xyz11", fontH5 );                        


          Phrase p2 = new Phrase();
          p2.Add(c3);                      

          Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
          p.Leading = 12;
          p.Add(p2);
          pdfDoc.Add(p);
          pdfDoc.Close();
```

My code works fine..